# How did Drago Bludvist tame a Bewilderbeast?

Tags: how-to-train-your-dragon

In the sequel, Drago was

> controlling an Alpha dragon.

AFAIK, he kind of had a scary aura that could tame smaller dragons, and dragons only respond to those with significant power.

**So how did he tame that gigantic beast when it was shown that**

> **it takes an Alpha to take an Alpha down?**

Comment: Not for nothing, but saying that the title is a spoiler doesn't really protect anyone from spoilers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [HTTYD Website](https://www.howtotrainyourdragon.com/explore/dragons/drago-bewilderbeast):

> Found as a hatchling during one of Drago Bludvist's earliest conquests, this particular Bewilderbeast suffered the misfortune of being raised by a madman.